# Hide tittle bar in ActionBarActivity using java code

Tags: java, android, android-actionbaractivity

how to hide title bar from Android ActionBarActivity
I have tried everything but did not get success.

getting that Exception :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.dan.msdashboard/com.dan.msdashboard.FirstActivity}:
>   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called
>   before adding content

but I am using this code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            // Hide the Title bar of this activity screen


        this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
```

Please help me solve .

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Change your ActionBarActivity to only Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do feature before onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            // Hide the Title bar of this activity screen


        this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once try as follows

```
     // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // Hide the Title bar of this activity screen
    this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
```

hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the window flags before calling `super.onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow()...
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`

If you are using `AppCompat`

add one `attribute` in the `activity` tag to hide `ActionBar`

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```